# Universal geometry

Tags: geometry, soft-question

Is there something analog as to what universal algebra is for algebra for geometry? Some formalism incorporating both analytical geometry, differential geometry and algebraic topology. Or what comes closest to connecting all these fields together?

Comment: My first thought is that where universal algebra concerns axioms for *varieties* and all possible models of these theories, the corresponding theme for universal geometry would involve axioms for incidence designs.  However this seems unlikely to lead to a unification of metric concepts as your question concerns.